# How does Rails' link_to work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, link-to

From the [docs](http://devdocs.io/rails~4.2/actionview/helpers/urlhelper#method-i-link_to):

```
link_to "Profile", profile_path(@profile)
# => <a href="/profiles/1">Profile</a>
link_to "Profile", @profile
# => <a href="/profiles/1">Profile</a>
```

There's a lot going on here. First, there is the method `#profile_path` which gets generated for the `Profile` resource. These types of methods get generated all the time.

- How does that work?
- Where would I read the documentation for a method that gets generated?

Then in the second example, the `profile_path` method is omitted.

- Does rails know it's in a view associated with the `Profile` resource?
- How does it know?

Also from the docs, the method signature for `link_to`:

```
link_to(body, url_options = {}, html_options = {})
```

Also here there is a lot going on. From the perspective of ruby `link_to` is a method that takes three [positional arguents](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/ruby-2-keyword-arguments#keyword-arguments-vs-positional-arguments), two of which are [optional](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/153013#674581). But the last two are hashes, so it's a little tricky to differentiate between the two unless we explicitly use curlies. So we need to be careful about whether trying to set the `url_options` or `html_options`.

- What's the difference between `url_options` and `html_options`?
- When and why would you use each?
- Can you provide a simple example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see all of your routes by running `rake routes` in your app root directory. Example:

```
                      Prefix Verb      URI Pattern                                                             Controller#Action
                negotiations GET       /negotiations(.:format)                                                 negotiations#index
                             POST      /negotiations(.:format)                                                 negotiations#create
             new_negotiation GET       /negotiations/new(.:format)                                             negotiations#new
            edit_negotiation GET       /negotiations/:id/edit(.:format)                                        negotiations#edit
                 negotiation GET       /negotiations/:id(.:format)                                             negotiations#show
                             PATCH     /negotiations/:id(.:format)                                             negotiations#update
                             PUT       /negotiations/:id(.:format)                                             negotiations#update
                             DELETE    /negotiations/:id(.:format)                                             negotiations#destroy
```

Thus you can use any of these prefixes with `_path` or `_url` at the end. I won't go into details on `_url` now as it's not directly relevant to your question.

Rails is able to map any object that you pass into `link_to` by its model. It actually has nothing to do with the view that you use it in. It knows that an instance of the `Profile` class should map to the `/profiles/:id` path when generating a URL. The precondition for this is that you're declaring the `Profile` routes in your `routes.rb` using the `resources` tag, e.g. `resources :profiles`.

`url_options` is for passing a URL or any options for it. It often involves magic that Rails has to perform first before the HTML can be rendered.

`html_options` is for passing settings to the link tag itself. The actual path itself goes in `url_options`, whereas `id`, `class`, etc. all go in `html_options`. Here's an example:

```
link_to "Profile", @profile, class: 'button'
```

The docs are a great reference on this. Check them out: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to